# How to change image path using htaccess?

Tags: image, .htaccess, path, url-rewriting

I'm fixing this joomla site. It uses joomla 1.7 language filter so it adds post fixes to the url. So when i view an artcle with images, image is not displaying.
I tried htaccess rewrite rules. But it didn't work for me... 
this is what i get when i copy image url.

```
http://domain.com/en/images/myimage.png
```

But when I check the code its `images/myimage.png` .
If i edit code to `/images/myimage.png` it works.

Tthis is what i try to do with htaccess too, to add a "/". Since it didn't work i guess i have to change whole url. 
I don't have much knowledge in rewriting. 
Can you guys help me please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give this a go in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/images/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This will rewrite your **/en/images/...** requests to **/images/...**

Note, this could have unexpected consequences for other URLs. I would suggest properly testing this on your own application.

Comment: hello, then all my other images disappears :(

Comment: What are your other image paths? Give me an example of one or two that are not working.

Comment: hey thanks save my time :) i edited it
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteRule ^en/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/en/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^de/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/de/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^pl/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/pl/images/(.*)$ /images/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>`
thats what i did, did it as i know maybe not so accurate ! but thaks a load!!

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess solution only works partially for me, so I fixed this from the template's index.php file.
Inside the `<head>` tag, after the `<jdoc:include type="head" />` code I added this code

```
<?php
//removed joomla autogenerated <base> tag
unset($doc->base); ?>
<base href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>">
```

Tested with Joomla 3.6.5