# I have image issues Joomla Multi-Language website

Tags: joomla, web

This problem occurs when I'm trying to load images through flash.

For example when i'm trying to load an image in images/001.jpg , Joomla rewrites it to en/images/001.jpg. So path get changed and flash cant load the file. Anyway to fix this ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the image load path in the htaccess file where the URL you want.

Comment: Can you make and example on how to do please ?  I have the same problem

Comment: @giuseppe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700990/how-to-change-image-path-using-htaccess