# htaccss how to set all file paths in project to be relative from root

Tags: php, apache

After long search i didn't find clear answer for this issue:
how to set  the htaccess file in my site that all paths will be relative to the root and no to the "current sub-folder".
example : "sub-folder/images/img.png" to root/images/img.png

Answer (score 0):

found answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9702083/6336750

RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^.*/images/(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/images/$1 [L,R=301]